# Как листать страницы во время парсинга сайтов?

Tags: python, парсер, пагинация

Не могли бы вы подсказать, каким образом можно менять страницу во время парсинга сайта? Проблема в том, что новые страницы открываются с помощью скрипта, то есть у каждой страницы нет нового url. Поэтому и нет идей, как надо организовать код, чтобы парсить все страницы, а не только первую. Парсить нужно только таблицу с иностранными ценными бумагами.
Спасибо!

Ссылка на сайт:
https://spbexchange.ru/ru/market-data/default.aspx

Comment: Посмотреть в инспекторе браузера на вкладке сетей какие запросы идут от сайта и попробовать повторить их. Либо использовать селениум или его аналог, чтобы через скрипт делать действия для перехода на новые страницы

Comment: А так, добавьте минимальный пример, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться тем, кто захочет помочь вам